# Spark Scala Dataframe: Dynamically transform a non-null column

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, dataset

I have a dataframe that contains N columns and for a subset of those I would like to dynamically apply a function on the column (or "access" this column) that is not null. Per row, only one column out of this subset is not null, but it can be any. This needs to work independently from the number of columns. E.g.:

Original dataframe with subset A,B and C:

```
Id | A    | B    | C     | ...
1  | text | null | null  | ...
2  | null | text | null  | ...
3  | null | null | text  | ...
```

Target dataframe:

```
Id | A    | B    | C     | ... | Result
1  | text | null | null  | ... | result of f(text)
2  | null | text | null  | ... | result of f(text)
3  | null | null | text  | ... | result of f(text)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) to generate a column that'll have the non-null value for that row, and apply your function on that column

This would work:

```
val cols = df.columns.filterNot(_.startsWith("id")).map(col(_))

df.withColumn("intermediateColumn", coalesce(cols: _*))
.withColumn("Result", YourFunction("intermediateColumn"))
```

Consider the below as input:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| id|    A|    B|    C|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  1|text1| null| null|
|  1| null|text2| null|
|  1| null| null|text3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
```

Dataframe with the intermediate column will be:

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
| id|    A|    B|    C|intermediateColumn|
+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
|  1|text1| null| null|             text1|
|  1| null|text2| null|             text2|
|  1| null| null|text3|             text3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------+
```

Output after applying a function:

The example function removes first letter of the string.

```
+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------+------+
| id|    A|    B|    C|intermediateColumn|Result|
+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------+------+
|  1|text1| null| null|             text1|  ext1|
|  1| null|text2| null|             text2|  ext2|
|  1| null| null|text3|             text3|  ext3|
+---+-----+-----+-----+------------------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot to mention that the column are of different types and coalesce expects an input of the same type.

Comment: Oh, well that changes everything!

Comment: The columns have different nested structures, each column represents a certain message type and I want to do the following steps only on the non-null column:

1. Check if conditions for certain fields within the column are true
2. Extract values from certain fields within the column where 1. is true. 

The type of the values returned are always strings.

Comment: You can create a struct of all the columns and drop the fields with null the use the single value.